# Reflection: Cast PropertyInfo to List<obj>

Tags: c#, reflection

As the title says, then I'm trying to cast a `PropertyInfo` to its "original" type, which is `List<obj>` in my case.

I've tried the code below without luck:

`(List<obj>)pInfo.GetValue(pInfo, null)`

`(List<obj>)pInfo.GetValue(typeof<obj>, null)`

It simply throws me an exception:

> TargetException was unhandled: Object
>   does not match target type.

I'm sure that I'm overlooking something extremely simple, but I cant figure out what.

Comment: One of the `pInfo` is wrong, but you don't show enough code to say which.

Comment: The first argument to GetValue is supposed to be the instance you're examining.  It looks like you're giving it the PropertyInfo object itself, which is suspicious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first parameter is the target object:

```
var list = (List<object>)prop.GetValue(obj,null);
```

Personally, though, I might be tempted to use the non-generic API here; generics and reflection rarely mix well:

```
var list = (IList)prop.GetValue(obj,null);
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you get `obj` from. Do I have to iterate something? All I want is simply to get the `List<obj>` thats "inside" the PropertyInfo.

Comment: @ebb: The PropertyInfo doesn't refer to the property of a particular *object*, it refers to a property of a *type*. For example, if you've got the `Bar` property and you're trying to get `foo.Bar`, you'd use `prop.GetValue(bar, null);`

Comment: @ebb unless it is a static property that makes no sense. The PropertyInfo is *metadata* about a property, not the *value* of a property in the context of a particular object. If you imagine a typical `personInstance.Name`, you need a target `personInstance` and a property `.Name`. Otherwise you are saying "There are 200 people. What is their Name?". you need to say *of which*

Comment: Thanks for: `IList`, _generics and reflection rarely mix well_.

Comment: 10 years later, this solution still saves asses! Thank you <3

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
(List<obj>)pInfo.GetValue(pInfo, null)
```

is wrong, the first argument to GetValue should be the object you're reading the property of, not the PropertyInfo itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the object you want to get the value for and not the type. Something like this.

```
List<obj> object ...

(List<obj>) pInfo.GetValue( object, null );
```